# So confused on how to write to a file repeatedly in one loop (python3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, file-io

I'm running a program the takes in data from other clients, and have been having an enormous amount of problems writing, and changing information in a file, and I feel like I have tried everything. I want to save the information in case the program stops for some reason, and so the data would have saved. I feel like i have tried everything, using `file.flush`, using `os.fsync()` with it, I have tried using `with open(file) as file:` statements to close the file when the program stops, and currently, I's trying atexit to have a function write to the file when it closes, which hasn't worked out, plus doesn't call on errors, so is kinda irrelevant. I'm looking for a way to write to a file, repeatedly, and, well, work. I may not understand something, so please explain it to me. I have been having trouble without end, and need help.

> EDIT

```
AccData = {}

client = discord.Client()
User = discord.User
def SaveData():
    pickle.dump(AccData,data)
    data.close()
    print("data saved")
atexit.register(SaveData)

f = open('DisCoin.json','rb')
AccData = pickle.load(open('DisCoin.json','rb'))
f.seek(0)
f.close()

data = open('DisCoin.json','wb')
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your code? the part that you're talking about, specially.

Comment: well-placed `somefile.flush()` commands should be all that is needed. Do you have a small demonstration program that we can test?

Comment: I can update it with the current atexit code, right now atleast

Comment: "write repeatedly in one loop". How about a few lines of that! Putting the loop in a `with` clause should be sufficient.

Comment: Using pickle to load a file called.json... um??

Comment: After a bit of cleanup, that code worked for me. having `data = open('DisCoin.json','wb')` sit around for the duration of your program is risky. If some other part of your code does something to unlink that file, you'll be writing to the wrong place. How about opening the file in the atexit handler?

Comment: atexit says it won't call the func from a fatal error, whats the difference between that and a normal error?

Comment: @tdelaney, I told you, I've tried everything ;D

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you mean. You've got normal badness covered, you are just worried about abnormal badness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python catches its own exceptions, most signals and exit() then runs `atexit` routines for cleanup. So, you can deal with normal badness there.

But other bad things happen. A segmenation fault or other internal error. An unknown signal. Code that calls `os._exit()`. These will cause an early termination and data not yet flushed will be lost. Bad things can happen to any program and if they need extra resiliency, they need some method to handle that.

- You can write things to temporary files and rename them to the "live" file only when they are complete. If a program terminates, at least its last saved data is still there.
- You can write a log or journal of changes and rebuild the data you want by scanning that log. That's how many file systems work, and "Big Data" map/reduce systems to basically the same thing.
- You can move to a database and use its transaction processing or any OLPT system to make sure you do all-or-none updates to your data store.

Your example code is especially fragile because

```
data = open('DisCoin.json','wb')
```

trashes existing data on disk. There is no going back with this code! Step one, then, is don't do that. Keep old data until the new stuff is ready.

Here is an example class that manages temporary files for you. Use it instead of `open` and it will create a temporary file for you to update and will only go live with the data of the `with` clause exits without an exception. There is no need for an atexit handler if you use this in a `with` clause.

```
import shutil
import os

class SidelineFile:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.args = list(args)
        self.kw = kw

    def __enter__(self):
        self.closed = False
        self.orig_filename = self.args[0]
        self.args[0] += '.tmp'
        try:
            mode = self.args[1]
        except IndexError:
            try:
                mode = self.kw['mode']
            except KeyError:
                mode = 'r'
        if 'a' in mode:
            shutil.copy2(self.orig_filename, self.args[0])
        self.file_obj = open(*self.args, **self.kw)
        return self.file_obj

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if not self.closed:
            self.file_obj.close()
            self.closed = True
        if not exc_type:
            os.rename(self.args[0], self.orig_filename)
        else:
            os.remove(self.args[0])


fn = 'test.txt'

with SidelineFile(fn, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write("foo")
print(1, repr(open(fn).read()))

with SidelineFile(fn, mode='a') as fp:
    fp.write("bar")
print(2, repr(open(fn).read()))

with SidelineFile(fn, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write("foo")
print(3, repr(open(fn).read()))

try:
    with SidelineFile(fn, 'a') as fp:
        fp.write("bar")
        raise IndexError()
except IndexError:
    pass
print(4, repr(open(fn).read()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like to achieve this by defining a print function for it.

```
import os

def fprint(text,**kwargs):
    os.chdir('C:\\mypath')
    myfile=open('output.txt','a')
    if kwargs:
        print(text,end=kwargs['end'],file=myfile)
    else:
        print(text,file=myfile)
    myfile.close()

fprint('Hello')
input()
fprint('This is here too',end='!!\n')
```

The above code will write 'Hello' into the file 'output.txt' at C:\mypath, save it, then after you enter some input will write 'This is here too!!' into the file. If you check the file while the script is waiting for input, it should already contain 'Hello'.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to click add comment (don't know if that affected you) Would it work the same if I did write instead of append?

Comment: It wouldn't. Write will overwrite the existing file when it closes, where as append seeks to the end of the open file and adds to it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask, would this function write to a file instead of append, if I changed the file's value to write?